# Adding views to LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android

I have seen other similar questions about it but noone helped me.
I'm trying to add an entire layout inside a LinearLayout, this is my current code:

**Main layout**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false">

         <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/linear_content">
            </LinearLayout>

         </HorizontalScrollView>

        <ProgressBar 
            android:id="@+id/fragment_alertas_lista_peoples_progress"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Layout to be added (item.xml)**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**And I'm trying to add views**

```
for (Person person : listPeople) {

        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView name = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.name);

        img.setImageBitmap(person.getImage().getBitmap());
        name.setText(person.getName().toString());

        linearContent.addView(item);
}
```

This doesn't works, doesn't add any view to linear layout. Someone has any idea about it?

Comment: from which Activity method are you invoking view-producing code?

Comment: @jmuet From another activity, this is a static method.

Comment: @Rafael Activity static methods are risky (e.g. can be called when activity layout is not inflated at all) I would rather recommend a listener pattern which would help decouple your two activities

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What exceptions end up in logcat?  If none, put logging into your code and see what that gives.

Comment: @ChrisStratton altough logcat doesnt show anything, nothing appears on LinearLayout.

Comment: Then add logging to your code to verify the success of each step, and see where that breaks down.

Comment: @jmuet I'll make the method as a non-static method.

Comment: Static vs. non-static is not really relevant here, though the original question of which Activity (lifecycle or UI) method is ultimately calling this, remains one that you need to answer.

Comment: About the inflater, I'm using inflater of OnCreateView method, is it right?

Comment: Post your whole method. For example how you obtain the inflater and linearContent